# How to configure spacing in a collection view cell that is the same as the leading edge with the navigation bar title?

Tags: uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, swift5

I have a UICollectionViewController where I want to display collection view cells where the left edge is aligned with the title of the navigation bar. I certainly don't want to hardcode the spacing of CGFloat 20 due to various device screen sizes. Given from my code below, the implementation looks fine on an iPhone 8+ and iPhone 11 Pro Max, but not the iPhone 11 (the collection view cell left edge is more to the right than the edge of the navigation bar title, as shown from the image below my code).

Does anyone know of a method to programmatically (or through Storyboards) align the leading edge of both the navigation bar title and collection view cell?

```
private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    private let spacing: CGFloat = 20 // CGFloat of 20 works well for the iPhone 8+ and iPhone 11 Pro Max, but not the iPhone 11 Pro

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Register cell classes
        self.collectionView!.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        // Setup layout
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: spacing, left: spacing, bottom: spacing, right: spacing)
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = spacing
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = spacing
        self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout = layout
    }

    // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 16
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = .systemFill
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let numberOfItemsPerRow: CGFloat = 2
        let spacingBetweenCells: CGFloat = spacing

        let totalSpacing = (2 * self.spacing) + ((numberOfItemsPerRow - 1) * spacingBetweenCells) // Amount of total spacing in a row

        if let collection = self.collectionView {
            let width = (collection.bounds.width - totalSpacing) / numberOfItemsPerRow
            return CGSize(width: width, height: width)
        } else {
            return CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I thought of a neat solution. Maybe a workaround but I am satisfied.

```
// Change private let spacing: CGFloat = 20 to
private var spacing = CGFloat()

// Upon loading, spacing will be initialized depending on screen width
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Added code
    if UIScreen.main.bounds.width <= 375 {
        spacing = 16 // For the iPhone 7, 8, 11 Pro
    } else {
        spacing = 20 // For the iPhone 7+, 8+ and 11 Pro Max
    }
}
```